# SonarCloud does not import coverlet code coverage

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarcloud

I've got a Azure DevOps pipeline running a SonarCloud analysis on a .NET solution. My pipeline looks like this:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .Net SDK 7'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.x'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Set up NuGet'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore solution'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  displayName: 'Prepare SonarCloud analysis configuration'
  inputs:
    # inputs

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build solution
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests and collect coverage
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
    projects: '**/*.Test.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true

# Install code coverage tool, then run it
- script: |
    dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
    reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.WorkFolder)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults -reporttypes:'HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura'
  displayName: Create code coverage report

# Publish the combined code coverage to the pipeline
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults/Cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults'

- task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
  displayName: 'Run SonarCloud analysis'

- task: SonarCloudPublish@1
  displayName: 'Publish results on build summary'
```

This pipeline correctly builds and publishes code coverage to Azure DevOps, but in the logs I can see that the JaCoCo sensor is being used to detect coverage. I've created the following sonar-project.properties file to remedy this, as the [documentation](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/enriching/test-coverage/test-coverage-parameters/#c) suggests:

```
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/CoverageResults/Cobertura.xml
sonar.coverageReportPaths=**/CoverageResults/Cobertura.xml
```

I've also tried all other properties to get sonar to use coverlet/opencover to import the xml file but it continues to use JaCoCo:

```
INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp] (done) | time=27ms
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=4ms
```

My question is basically: what am I doing wrong?

In the logs it says `'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations`, so I've also tried adding that property to see if it does register as defined, but the logs keep saying `'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations`. This almost certainly confirms that the property file is not read/found/used. How can I verify/remedy this?

EDIT:

It does use OpenCover to read files! While analyzing projects it gives the jacoco error on every project, but at the end of the analysis the following logs can be found:

```
10:52:04.687 WARN: Could not import coverage report '/home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az362-389_2024-01-12_10_50_50/In/fv-az362-389/coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in /home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az362-389_2024-01-12_10_50_50/In/fv-az362-389/coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
10:52:04.688 DEBUG: The current user dir is '/home/vsts/work/1'.
10:52:04.688 INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report /home/vsts/work/_temp/36304613-f19c-4f5c-a98f-7312cff254c4/coverage.cobertura.xml
10:52:04.689 WARN: Could not import coverage report '/home/vsts/work/_temp/36304613-f19c-4f5c-a98f-7312cff254c4/coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in /home/vsts/work/_temp/36304613-f19c-4f5c-a98f-7312cff254c4/coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
10:52:04.689 DEBUG: The current user dir is '/home/vsts/work/1'.
10:52:04.689 INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report /home/vsts/work/_temp/20fc0c63-9b9c-4596-9dd8-e9895e44a7ed/coverage.cobertura.xml
10:52:04.690 WARN: Could not import coverage report '/home/vsts/work/_temp/20fc0c63-9b9c-4596-9dd8-e9895e44a7ed/coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in /home/vsts/work/_temp/20fc0c63-9b9c-4596-9dd8-e9895e44a7ed/coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
10:52:04.690 DEBUG: The current user dir is '/home/vsts/work/1'.
10:52:04.690 INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report /home/vsts/work/_temp/45be504f-f9ed-444a-be8a-f504da051afe/coverage.cobertura.xml
10:52:04.691 WARN: Could not import coverage report '/home/vsts/work/_temp/45be504f-f9ed-444a-be8a-f504da051afe/coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in /home/vsts/work/_temp/45be504f-f9ed-444a-be8a-f504da051afe/coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
10:52:04.691 DEBUG: The current user dir is '/home/vsts/work/1'.
10:52:04.691 INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report /home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az362-389_2024-01-12_10_50_42/In/fv-az362-389/coverage.cobertura.xml
10:52:04.692 WARN: Could not import coverage report '/home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az362-389_2024-01-12_10_50_42/In/fv-az362-389/coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in /home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az362-389_2024-01-12_10_50_42/In/fv-az362-389/coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
10:52:04.692 DEBUG: Analyzing coverage after aggregate found '0' coverage files.
10:52:04.693 DEBUG: The total number of file count statistics is '0'.
```

It's finding all my coverage reports now, but I'm getting an error. Is it something with my dotnetcli test command that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Cobertura is not compatible with OpenCover anymore. Using

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests and collect coverage
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
    projects: '**/*.Test.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true
```

results in a Cobertura xml. The file cannot be imported by sonar because Cobertura differs from OpenCover. It seems Sonars documentation on Cobertura is incorrect, since they specify

```
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths

Comma-delimited list of paths to the coverage reports produced by OpenCover or Coverlet.
```

And they have multiple examples that are doing this. Turns out, this doesn't work. I have changed my coverage output format to OpenCover and now it works!

```yaml
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  displayName: 'Prepare SonarCloud analysis configuration'
  inputs:
    #inputs
    extraProperties: |
            sonar.tests=**/*.Test.csproj
            sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=**/*.trx
            sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Agent.WorkFolder)/**/coverage.opencover.xml

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build solution
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests and collect coverage
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage;Format=opencover"'
    projects: '**/*.Test.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true


# Install code coverage tool, then run it
- script: |
    dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
    reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.WorkFolder)/**/coverage.opencover.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults -reporttypes:'HtmlInline_AzurePipelines_Dark;Cobertura'
  displayName: Create code coverage summary report

# Publish the combined code coverage to the pipeline
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage summary report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults/Cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults'
    
- task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
  displayName: 'Run SonarCloud analysis'

- task: SonarCloudPublish@1
  displayName: 'Publish results on build summary'
```